# Error when creating a payment intent in Stripe

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm creating a payment intent in Stripe, with my test API key. My python code looks like:

```
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_*"
response = stripe.PaymentIntent.create({'amount': amount,'currency': currency,'description': description, 'customer': customer})
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/stripe/api_resources/abstract/createable_api_resource.py", line 22, in create
    response, api_key = requestor.request("post", url, params, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 121, in request
resp = self.interpret_response(rbody, rcode, rheaders)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 372, in interpret_response
self.handle_error_response(rbody, rcode, resp.data, rheaders)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 151, in handle_error_response
raise err
stripe.error.AuthenticationError: Invalid API Key provided: {'amount******************************************************nt'}
```

What is going on? Why is my API key not valid? Why do I couldn't create a payment intent in test mode?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first parameter is not a keyword argument, it must be the API key. The function's signature is (see `stripe/api_resources/creatable-api_resource.py`):

```
stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
    cls,
    api_key=None,
    idempotency_key=None,
    stripe_version=None,
    stripe_account=None,
    **params
)
```

So you should omit the braces, because the dictionary is given as first parameter to `api_key`:

```
response = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
    'amount': amount, 'currency': currency,
    'description': description, 'customer': customer)
```